# SQL - How can I check to see if a FIELD A has all 3 specific values in FIELD B?

Tags: sql

My table "actions" has the following fields: (unique) id, transactionNumber (varchar) and status (varchar).

The status can be equal to 'New', 'Started', 'Update', 'Error', 'Completed'

I need a query that will only return the transactionNumbers (from my table "actions") that have all 3 status ('New', 'Started','Completed') in different rows. We don't need to worry about 'Update' or 'Error'.

I need this because a transactionNumber can not have one of those 3 status missing.

Thank you very much in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can achieve this by using `COUNT` with `DISTINCT`:

```
SELECT TransactionNumber 
FROM Actions
WHERE Status IN('New', 'Started', 'Completed')
GROUP BY TransactionNumber
HAVING COUNT(DISTINCT Status) = 3
```